# On click of a Button , how to make the drop down to back to default selection

Tags: jquery

I have a drop down with two buttons as shown below

```
<select id="BrandNames" class="m-wrap" tabindex="1" style="width:100%;">
   <option class="placeholder" selected="" disabled="">Select Brand</option>
   <option value="3000">General</option>
   <option value="3001">KFC</option>
   <option value="3002">Chutneys</option>
</select>
  <input type="button" id="prev"  value="prev">

  <input type="button" id="next" value="Next">

$(document).on('click', '#prev', function(event ) {
alert('Prev button called');
});



$(document).on('click', '#next', function(event ) {
alert('Next button called');
});
```

Assume that i selected General (First Option) from the drop down menu .

My requirement is that if i select **Next** button Or **previous** Button , how can i make the drop down to back to default selection that is Select Brand in my case ??

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8f9c71x3/

could anybody please help .

Comment: Areyou able to wrap the select with a form?
Than you can call reset on the form and the select will automatically reset to default :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:-

```
<select id="BrandNames" class="m-wrap" tabindex="1" style="width:100%;">
   <option class="placeholder" selected="" disabled="" value="">Select Brand</option>
   <option value="3000">General</option>
   <option value="3001">KFC</option>
   <option value="3002">Chutneys</option>
</select>
  <input type="button" id="prev"  value="prev">

  <input type="button" id="next" value="Next">
```

as shown above add `value=""` in `Select Brand` option of dropdown.

Jquery :-

```
$(document).on('click', '#prev', function(event ) {
   alert('Prev button called');
   $('#BrandNames').val(''); //select first option
});

$(document).on('click', '#next', function(event ) {
    alert('Next button called');
    $('#BrandNames').val(''); //select first option 
});
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8f9c71x3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you can find current selected option. based on next/prev click, target next/prev element and set its selected property to true:

```
$(document).on('click', '#prev', function(event ) {
   $('#BrandNames option:Selected').prev().prop('selected','true')
});
$(document).on('click', '#next', function(event ) {
  $('#BrandNames option:Selected').next().prop('selected','true');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5n6Lxps1/)**